# Load custom SubView's programatically like if they were Cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, swift2

I use to had a tableView with custom cells showing shops:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell : shopsTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("shopCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! shopsTableViewCell
```

But since we added a scroll view in the main view, and apple don't recommend/allow to mix `scrollView` and `tableView`, I deleted the table view and replaced the custom cells with custom `UIView`'s. 
I would like to proceed with the same behavior: 
1 - detect how many values are inside an array. 
2 - instantiate a UIView for each array index
3 - set that UIView with values like image, position, constraints, etc
4 - Add it to the current View.

I'm using storyboard and I don't see anywhere how to instantiate the custom UIView from storyboard. Also this UIView is a subView that is inside a ViewController.

I did a custom UIView class with outlets:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
class connectedShop : UIView{

    @IBOutlet weak var bannerViewHight: NSLayoutConstraint!

    @IBOutlet weak var bannerViewTop: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var bannerViewLeft: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var bannerViewRight: NSLayoutConstraint!

    @IBOutlet weak var banerDiscount: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var bannerImageShop: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var bannerTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var bannerDescription: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var bannerButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func bannerButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {

    }

}
```

In my storyboard I have connected the subView "connected shop" to this custom class. Also set the storyboard Id to customView:

[image]

I want to instantiate this custom subView, one for each connected shop, like I use to do in tableView.
I've try this but it's crashing

```
let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
                let viewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("customView")
```

I've also tried to create a new custom class, without outlets:

```
    import Foundation
import UIKit
class customShop : UIView{

    var bannerViewHight: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var bannerViewTop: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var bannerViewLeft: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var bannerViewRight: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var banerDiscount: UIImageView!
    var bannerImageShop: UIImageView!
    var bannerTitle: UILabel!
    var bannerDescription: UILabel!
    var bannerButton: UIButton!

}
```

and trying this:

```
var connectedShop : customShop = customShop()

                connectedShop.bannerTitle.text = "custom Shop"
                self.view.addSubview(connectedShop)
```

But it's crashing with this error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: i think so it is navigation problem

Answer (score 0):

```
let shopVw = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("customView") as! shopViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(shopVw, animated: true) // this is the code for navigation
```

Comment: My custom view class inherits from UIView. Your code is for a UIViewController but I have a UIView and I'm getting this error: 
Cannot convert value of type 'connectedShop' to expected argument type 'UIViewController'

Answer (score 0):

Try to load nib and cast it to your class:

```
let view = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("YourClassView", owner: self, options: nil).first as! YourClassView
```

Caveat: you can load xib in `viewDidLoad`, but you should manipulate with the view in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` in order to have constraint set and running and therefore your view sized properly.

Comment: I'm having a crash. The reason I think is because the subView I'm trying to instantiate is inside a scene in storyboard, not in a nib file. 
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle <xxxxxx> (loaded)' with name 'customView''